# Installation issues with Passenger with Apache on OS X 10.8

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to get Passenger working on Mountain Lion after the upgrade from 10.7, but I'm having issues when running `passenger-install-apache2-module`:

```
g++ ext/apache2/HelperAgent.cpp -o agents/apache2/PassengerHelperAgent -Iext -Iext/common -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<ext/hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libboost_oxt.a -lpthread  
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_regcompA", referenced from:
      Passenger::FilterSupport::Filter::Value::Value(bool, Passenger::StaticString const&, bool)in libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o)
      Passenger::FilterSupport::Filter::Value::initializeFrom(Passenger::FilterSupport::Filter::Value const&)in libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o)
  "_regexecA", referenced from:
      Passenger::FilterSupport::Filter::Comparison::compareStringOrRegexp(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Passenger::FilterSupport::Context const&)in libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o)
  "_regfreeA", referenced from:
      Passenger::FilterSupport::Filter::Value::freeStorage()    in libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ ext/apache2/HelperAgent.cpp -o agents/...]
```

All the required software checks are green.

I've installed the PCRE headers as suggested in the [Phusion blog post](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/10/26/fixing-nginx-pcre-compilation-issues-on-os-x-2/), although that was a bit of a gamble since it's aimed at Nginx issues.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks, 
Griff

Comment: are you using a packet manager? I had the same issue with homebrew and fixed it by uninstalling homebrew and reinstalling everything.

Comment: I'm installing Passenger from the gem. I do have homebrew installed, though I'm pretty sure that Apache, Ruby etc. weren't installed through it. Might be worth uninstalling it and trying again in any event

Comment: Try uninstalling boost if you have installed it with homebrew. For me that was the deal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a separate problem from the PCRE problem. Phusion Passenger uses [regexp functions from the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html).

At first appearance, this error seems to be implying that OS X 10.8 does not support POSIX regexp functions. But that would be a very strange conclusion seeing that:

- 10.6 and 10.7 supported them just fine.
- the header file regex.h is available, otherwise you would get a compiler error about regex.h missing instead of this linker error.
- even Apple [claims to officially support it](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/regcomp.3.html).

The only conclusion I can draw at the moment is that either your system is broken, or OS X 10.8 has become broken. I am on holidays right now, ping times to Europe and the US are over 1000+ ms, and I don't have OS X 10.8, so I cannot further analyze the problem right now. As such, short-term advice I can give you are:

- Reinstall your system.
- Contact Apple for support.